# How do I create a FileInfo object from an HttpPostedFileBase object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a FileUpload control that passes the HttpPostedFileBase as a parameter into my controller.  Currently in the controller, I save the HttpPostedFileBase, and get the full path by hard coding it.  I need a way to simply access the HttpPostedFileBase from the FileUpload control, and turn it into a FileInfo object WITHOUT saving it.  I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I am still struggling to grasp the concept and differences of all of the different type of HttpPostedFileBase/FileInfo/etc. file "things".  I'd appreciate anyone's help!

Comment: That's not possible. Fileinfo inherits from FileSystemInfo which can be a file or a directory(thats why DirectoryInfo exists). So, its not possible to do it. You have to save the file in disk and load it with the path. FileInfo its not a Stream.

Answer (score 2):

*I made a comment about this and i decided to added as an answer.*

That's not possible. `Fileinfo` inherits from [FileSystemInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo(v=vs.110).aspx) which can be a file or a directory(thats why [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) exists). So, its not possible to do it. You have to save the file in disk and load it with the path.

[FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) its not a [Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx).